# Android Firebase Exception "Could not resolve type T"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi have an abstract generic class "ArticleOrdered" and a subclass "DrinkOrdered" (see code below for class declaration). If i create a DrinkOrdered object and i save it in Firebase, I have no problems.
When i try to execute:

```
DrinkOrdered test = dataSnapshot.getValue(DrinkOrdered.class);
```

to get the object, i have

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve type T
```

ArticleOrdered class:

```
public abstract class ArticleOrdered<T extends Article> {
private int quantity;
private T article;
private String note;
private double price;

public ArticleOrdered(int quantity, T article, String note) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.article = article;
    this.note = note;
    this.price = article.getPrice();
}

public ArticleOrdered() {
    //FIREBASE CONSTUCTOR
}

public T getArticle() {
    return article;
}

public void setArticle(T article) {
    this.article = article;
}
...
```

DrinkOrdered class:

```
public class DrinkOrdered extends ArticleOrdered<Drink> {

public DrinkOrdered(int quantity, Drink article, String note) {
    super(quantity, article, note);
}

public DrinkOrdered() {
    //FIREBASE CONSTRUCTOR
}
```

I have another class "PizzaOrdered" (but it is not important now)

TestActivity code:

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference orderRef = db.getReference("prova");
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DrinkOrdered a = dataSnapshot.getValue(DrinkOrdered.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("PIERF", "onCancelled");
        }
    };
    orderRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

is it correct to declare them in this way? Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself, using Jackson with these 2 lines of code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DrinkOrdered a = mapper.convertValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), DrinkOrdered.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my app, managed to fix it by casting the object myself:

```
DrinkOrdered a = (DrinkOrdered) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i have this exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to gruppo35.brickbreaker.appagato.database.order.DrinkOrdered"